# Django Permission by Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, permissions

I have this Classes

```
class Group(models.Model):
    GroupName = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Content(models.Model):
    Content = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    GroupName = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Group')
```

in Django i have some user accounts. How to Limit they rights on the Contentview by the groupname. So User A can only see Content where GroupName is "Content A" and User AB can see Content where GroupName is "Content A" and "Content B"

Short, how to limit the view by permission on a attribute in a class

A example:

View from User A on Content:

```
Content    GroupName
test1a     A
test2a     A
test3a     A
test4a     A
```

View from User AB on Content:

```
Content    GroupName
test1a      A
test1b      B
test2a      A
test2b      B
test3a      A
test3b      B
test4a      A
test4b      B
```

So I can give permissions by Groupname

Comment: where is the relationship between groups and users?

Comment: I'm using the admin site of Django. There are default user and groups.

Comment: In my example the group class is not the group of users. It's only there to group the content.